# How do I create an outline layer for multiple blocks of points?

Tags: points-to-line

I have a series of points that mark the edges of excavation units, I would like to create a layer of an outline connecting the points. The end goal is a layer displaying a grid of the excavation units. I've tried the points-to-line feature, but the only success is creating horizontal lines using Northing and Easting as line and sorting features. At one point, I was able to use the selection and construction tools to complete the outline and have it selected, but not only could I not save that data as a layer or new shapefile, I have four separate blocks of excavation units marked and starting on another block automatically cleared the selected grid.

I'm [including a photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIUZP.jpg) showing the situation, the red Xs mark the corners of units, they are each a single point.

I would like a layer that is a grid, demonstrated in part by the black lines drawn on the picture.

Comment: Use method explained http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164291/create-polygons-from-points-representing-the-corner-vertices-arcgis/164432#164432 and dissolve them into groups afterwards

Comment: Thanks, I had already checked out this thread, but I appreciate the direction.

Answer (score 1):

You're close to solution. Not sure which software you use, here is a recipe for QGIS

1. Calculate Northings and Eastings for all points:
   Vector/Geometry/Export\Add Geometry
2. Use Point2One plugin to convert points to lines based on attributes which will be your N/E. You'll have to do it twice, first for N, then for E. They should be the same and form straight line.
3. Combine two resulting shape-files with lines into one with
   Vector/Data management/Merge

Comment: Thank you so much! Although I was not using QGIS, this was sufficient for me to translate into the ArcGIS system and worked perfectly. I very much appreciate the help.