# Creating rotated fishnet from grid of evenly spaced points in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, vector-grid, grids-graticules

I am working with climate models, so I have a point shapefile representing the grid of data points of my climate models. My points are sort of evenly spaced along both directions, the distance being 1,500 m.

This grid is rotated but the rotation angle was not easy to determine, so I skipped this passage. I need to create a fishnet that follows the same rotation as the grid, so that there is one and only one grid point in each square of the fishnet.

How can this be done in ArcGIS?

If I assign the coordinates of my four corners, then they are not included in the fishnet but lay on the border. I want the fishnet to "begin" with an offset of 750 m in each direction with respect to the four corners.

My version is 10.3.1.

This is an image of the grid and a made up fishnet to convey the idea.
[image]

Comment: The Create Fishnet Tool does support a rotation value. Actually, you specify it by giving a second point on the "y" axis. Another awkward solution would be to buffer the points, then build the minimum bounding rectangles on the buffers.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131913/finding-the-boundary-polygon-from-a-set-of-gridded-points-no-hole/132052#132052

Comment: Have you tried using Create Thiessen Polygons?

it's not a grid but it may complete what you need to do with the given points.